# drupal front page rendering on admin pages

Tags: drupal-7

When I look at various pages in my drupal 7 admin pages, the blocks from my page--front.tpl.php page are showing up above my content.

This started happening when I removed the ckeditor from the modules folder and replaced it with another coeditor folder from another durpal site. Not a good move I realized.

It's an intermittent behavior. Sometimes it displays the blocks, sometimes it doesn't. I've tried flushing the cache, uninstalling coeditor and reinstalling it, but I'm not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion would be to restore from backup before you did the changes.

If you have created more content from that time the [node export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export) module could help you export and re-import it. And if you have created views or tother infrastructure [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) can be your friend.

Comment: This is a development site and unfortunately was not backed up.